# Cannot run PowerBi Visuals

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to Power BI. I want to replace an existing control with my custom control (like Date slicer with my custom calendar). I created a new visual project by following the instructions described in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/custom-visual-develop-tutorial) tutorial. When I run using the command `pbiviz start`, it throws error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Hope I get some solution.

Lot of Thanks in advance.

Comment: your npm package is looking for backward compatibility version as shown, research around installing any dependencies it lacks.

Comment: Do I need to install any dependency by myself.If so, what should I do..??